# Shiny app (free version launched in Linux server) errors at 60 seconds while uploading file using fileInput

Tags: r, file-upload, shiny, file-io, timeout

When running my Shiny app as home user (from Linux home directory) I am able to upload a file(appx 500Mb) using fileInput with no issues. But after launching the app in Linux server under /srv/shiny-server the app timeouts at exact 60 seconds with error as "error" for the same file.

I have tried the below but still having issues.

1. `options(shiny.maxRequestSize=500*1024^2)`
2. Changed the config file to `app_init_timeout 300` and `app_idle_timeout 1800` in /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf and /opt/Shiny/config/default.config
3. Added `http_keepalive_timeout 1800` in both config files.
4. I have tried including `autoInvalidate` with `reactiveTimer` to server function and few other code tries.
5. Explored ShinyFiles package, but I need to use local system files.

I need the app to allow atleast 1GB file.

I am not sure what I am missing. Any inputs/suggestions on this would be of great help.

Comment: Is there an error in the log file? Should be somewhere like /var/log/shiny-server/name_of_app.log

Comment: There are no errors in log. Added sanitise_errors FALSE and preserve_errors TRUE to config files. But no errors are displayed for this timeout.

Comment: Please clarify: Does the app only error 60 seconds into uploading? Or does it error after 60 seconds regardless of uploading?

Comment: When the file uploading time is less than 60 seconds, I don't see issues and File gets uploaded successfully. When I upload a big file, the upload time is more than 60 seconds (fileInput), it hard stops at 60 seconds and displays as "error" in the progress bar. The records loaded until the error is read and accessible.